# How to disable the page when popup is displayed

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, popup, popupwindow

I am trying to display a popup on a page. The desired behavior is to have the page in background where as the popup will be displayed on it. When the popup is displayed I am still able to make interaction with the background page. But I need to disable the background page.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Pivot IsEnabled="{Binding IsPopUpOpen , Converter={StaticResource BooleanInversionConverter}}">
        </Pivot>
    </Grid>

    <Popup Name="Popup" IsOpen="{Binding IsPopUpOpen}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBox Foreground="Black" FontSize="28" FontWeight="Normal" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="440"/>
    </Popup>

</Grid>
```

When I run this code, I am getting an exception :

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled Message: An unhandled
>   exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Windows.ni.dll Additional information: Cannot resolve
>   TargetName Img.

Let me know how to disable the pivot using MVVM approach.

Answer (score 0):

Juste place your popup above all other control.
Exemple:

```
<grid>
  <yourxaml>
</grid>
<popup horizontalAlignement="Stretch" verticalignementAlignement="Stretch"></popup>
```

Here, user can't have interaction with other part of application because your control popup is above all other.

Comment: the background of the popup will create a overlay then. I want the page to be visible. Popup normally doesnt hide the whole screen.

Comment: Oh you want show popup and don't show the app in background? really strange but why not create an generic page for show your message? Page w

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to subscribe to the Opened and Closed events get the Window and disable the Window itself. I have a child class so I opted to override instead since I want a draggable Popup. Below works for me.

```
        protected override void OnOpened(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnOpened(e);

            var parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);

            parentWindow.IsEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnClosed(e);

            var parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);

            parentWindow.IsEnabled = true;
        }
```